# Add image to a font for a specific character

Tags: fonts

I'm looking to add an image to a font which is already existing one. Its a free font too. I googled. But, there is no enough help on google to find solution.
Please help me with your advice.

Use case:
When I write ~100, 
It should appear [image]100

The red image you see is an image. Ideally it'll be same aspect ratio as th text letter is.

Is there anyway I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/), which helps to create a custom fonts with your own icons.

you can also have look on their tool which does it [icomoon app](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select)